# chrome.windows.create not working in Tor extension

Tags: tor, add-on, browser-extension

I've written an add-on / extension for the Tor browser. As we know, Tor is equivalent to Firefox. So, the extension I created works like a charm in Firefox, but in Tor, not so good.

So, this is what I'm trying to do inside the background script:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: `popup.html`,
  type: 'popup',
  height: 800,
  width: 900
});
```

In Tor, the popup is opened, but remains black/empty, nothing is happening inside the window

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Tor test",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "background",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon-off-128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
      "popup.html"
  ],
}
```

Any suggestions why the popup doesn't display any content inside that popup?